# cannot convert 'DATA_UNIT::getc1' from type 'char (DATA_UNIT::)()' to type 'char'

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks

```
char getc1(){return this->c1;}
```

I got this method as a get

```
DATA_UNIT::DATA_UNIT(const DATA_UNIT& Clone)
{
this->c1=Clone.getc1;
this->c2=Clone.getc2;
this->c3=Clone.getc3;
}
```

After using it, I get this error:

```
cannot convert 'DATA_UNIT::getc1' from type 'char (DATA_UNIT::)()' to type 'char'
```

Comment: get1c is a function so you need `get1c()`

Comment: If your copy constructor just copies each member, then you don't need to provide one. It is generated automatically.

Comment: That's not the problem, also using the parentheses i got the same error.

Comment: What is c1? There's not enough code here to replicate the issue.

Comment: private:
        char c1;
        char c2;
        char c3;

Comment: Please provide a complete source code example that shows the issue so I can compile it.

Comment: just access the meber directly:  `c1 = Clone.c1; c2 = Clone.c2; c3 = Clone.c3;`

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/q7KKK7vHFvvJm6wKEGwqSY

Comment: There are some design issues in your pasted code. You use the initialization list for the default constructor but not for the char parameter constructor or copy constructor. That's not a big deal but inconsistent. Also, you can put your default constructor body in the implementation file too. Assignment operator should return non-const. Your operator== and != are missing two consts each and your get functions are missing consts. I would suggest you do not write a copy constructor or assignment opeartor as the automatically generated ones are fine, although maybe this is a learning exercise.

Comment: I solved the issue removing the const in the DATA_UNIT::DATA_UNIT(const DATA_UNIT& Clone);

Answer (score 2):

With your source code, it's obvious that getcN are methods, so you *must* call them to get chars, which is exactly what the error is telling you: "Can't convert something that takes arguments to a char".

Also, as was already pointed out in the comments, there's no use in using this->c1 to access a member. Just c1 will do.

Comment: oh..i see..wrong source
That's the right one:
http://paste.ofcode.org/cvFtHtdbTBpKw2y2FWzmWy